# Straightening out jagged edges after live trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, live-trace

I'm trying to smooth out the edges of a low res jpeg download after I take it in to live trace and use the b&w preset. Is there a better way than using the anchor point tool?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the "smooth" tool located as a secondary option to the pencil tool.

Hard to predict and takes getting use to, but simply take it and smooth near/on lines you want to smooth and it will lessen the number of anchors giving a smoother line appearance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the **Smooth Tool** you can use `Object > Path > Simplify` from the menu to reduce the number of anchor points in any shape.